# How to Convert particle actions to an animation so I can import it to unity

Tags: particles, export, unity, file-format

Currently I'm struggling with simulating particles in blender and render it in unity

So here is the problem,
I have a particle simulation in my scene with molecular addon activated (don't worry about the addon). I just want to take the simulation and import it into unity

We can export it as an alembic file but in alembic all the particles get converted into a mesh and the simulation becomes too performance intensive

So, is there any performance friendly way to import the simulation into unity?

Here is a basic test scene "Test.blend"

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Agh4ZkKVOL987dUrbTUsJqFTX3pNOAr4/view?usp=drivesdk

Here is the kind of simulation I want to render in real time

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LKVKN7MLTAW3mYhaLSUUFzmqGOOaXWgI/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out

We just have to export the object that has the particle system in it as an alembic file format

Then we will delete everything in the scene and import the alembic file we just exported

Right after the importation is completed you will see that every particle you had has been converted into an object

Now you just have to export this as a .fbx file format and after the exporting window has opened you will see a tab in the right side of the window

Scroll down in that tab and expand the animation property and just uncheck "all action" and then export

Done